# "ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer" importing data from Spatialite into PostGIS through DB Manager

Tags: qgis, postgis, spatialite

I am trying to import data from Spatialite into PostGIS through drag and drop in DB Manager but all I received was an error:

`Feature write errors:   Creation error for features from #1 to #202. Provider errors was:   PostGIS error while adding features: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""`

[image]

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After inspections, I found my Spatialite Integer columns contain "" - fixed it by turning them all to null and import again.